# Storage method for paths of nodes for querying sub-paths

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to save paths into a MySQL database?

For example, there are two paths From A(source) to X(destination):

```
A->B->c->D->E->X
A->B->H->X
```

When someone requests paths from A to X, both paths are returned.
When someone requests paths from B to D, it returns just the first path.

Someone suggested me to use XML and save it into the data-base.

Is it possible? If yes, how can i SELECT these paths from the data-base?

Comment: most likely you would not use xml and a database at the same time, but either or or neither. how many paths do you have? how often are they going to be queried? is it performance critical?

Comment: actually it's most of the path of an country. yes performance is critical @hoijui

Comment: how about geo spatial then, where it belongs. I can go from here to next door probably 9B ways in Lichtenstein, but probably only 3 ways make any sense

Comment: @Drew would you explain more or give me any link that can help plz